# Creating a CocoaPod lib in local repository (without github source)

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In Podspec I need to specify a Github URL in 'source'? Can't I just use a local repository like Maven or Grunt? Then I just save the modifications and make a pod install in the projects that are using it.

Comment: IF your wanting to test you can always throw podspec in `~/.cocopaods/master` folder

Comment: Should I just copy the file .podspec and put in this folder?

Comment: Follow the conventions there. Make a folder for the podspec and a version folder (should be apparent when you look at the others in that folder). Also that folder is hidden, so you may need to use terminal.

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it, I will try it and let you know :)